# Web API methods to fill ComboBoxes?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have a bunch of `ComboBoxes` in my **AngularJS** web application that need to be filled. For the front-end, the only data I need is **lists of Key, Value pairs**.

The problem is for the back-end: in order to fill those lists, I have generated **a single Web API** endpoint that provides "lists of things".

The route is `/api/list/{id}`

Depending on the value of `{id}`, it will return lists of `Users`, `Accounts`, `Books`, `Cars`... in the same of key, value. For example, for the Id=1, it will return a list of Cars:

```
{1, "Ford" }, {1, "Toyota"}, {3, "Honda" } ...
```

That will be perfect for filling the ComboBoxes.

So... I have a **BIG SWITCH** inside the method in my controller to determine which kind list I should return.

I feel this is really dirty for the back-end, although for the front-end is quite handy. Just calling the same endpoint with a different magic number, I will get a different list.

My question: Is there a better and cleaner approach for this scenario?

Comment: IMO keep the controller thin and create a BigSwitchService (or whatever you will call it) which you inject in the controller. Keep all logic in the service. Regarding the api design, mayby not the cleanest api but if it will save you lot of time then you should use it

Answer (score 1):

This would usually be split in Controllers per data type ie. `UserController`, `AccountController` etc. Then each controller would have its action `List`.
Later, if needed, additional actions would be added to each controller (create/delete/etc.) and everything stays clean.
On the frontend you would have change your code just to not send magic number as a parameter but as part of the address:

- /api/**User**/List/{id}
- /api/**Account**/List/{id}

Comment: I do not think that this will cover his needs. He wants the same url with different number. At least this is what I understood from what he wrote. 

**Just calling the same endpoint with a different magic number, I will get a different list.**

Comment: @pitaridis I don't necessarily need a magic number. Instead, I would like to know it it's a good idea to concentrate all the list in one endpoint like this. Would you do that or would you do what Shadowed said?

Comment: It is not a good idea to put everything in one action. It is better to split it to multiple action.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute routing to map an id to a specific action.

First action with ID 1:

```
[Route("/api/list/1")]
```

Second action with ID 2:

```
[Route("/api/list/2")]
```